# Why SDL_RenderCopy and SDL_RenderCopyEx take non-const textures?

Tags: c++, constants, sdl-2

I'm optimizing my SDL code and adding const qualifiers wherever possible and stumbled upon the following declaration of SDL_RenderCopy:

```
int SDL_RenderCopy(SDL_Renderer*   renderer,
                   SDL_Texture*    texture,
                   const SDL_Rect* srcrect,
                   const SDL_Rect* dstrect)
```

The texture argument is not const.
Is there a reason why the texture should be non-const?
I thought that this function takes the texture as a source only and doesn't modify it.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: RenderCopy keeps track of when texture was used by modifying `texture->last_command_generation`: https://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/355a4f94a782/src/render/SDL_render.c#l2997

```
texture->last_command_generation = renderer->render_command_generation;

retval = QueueCmdCopy(renderer, texture, &real_srcrect, &real_dstrect);
```

This tracking is needed for cases when you heavily modify texture (e.g. destroy) while it is queued for rendering. On destroy, SDL checks for generation and flushes rendering queue if required. Otherwise it would be problemmatic to implement something (not very good) like "create texture, fill data, draw, destroy texture right away".

While is possible to modify SDL to keep generations in some separate place (e.g. renderer) but is this case logically "const" is questionable - you've queued texture for rendering, modifying it between that and RenderPresent is probably a bad idea, so.. not so const?

Comment: If the last_command_generation field is observable outside of the Renderer then I agree it should not be const since some outside code may depend on this value. But if it's only observed from within the RenderCopy function then the user code should still see the texture as const. Or maybe I'm thinking too much with encapsulation in mind.

Comment: Entire SDL_Texture is internal to SDL; struct layout is never exposed to calling side. If you continue that way, you'll end with const everywhere, including destroy (and a lot of const casts)? Anyway, it isn't how SDL implemented.